# Regex pattern matches fine but output is not complete

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying this regex pattern:

```
$string = '<div class="className">AlwaysTheSame:</div>Subtitle <br /><span class="anotherClass">entry1</span><span class="anotherClass">entry2</span><span class="anotherClass">entry3</span>';
preg_match_all('|<div class="className">AlwaysTheSame:</div>(.*?)<br />(<span class="anotherClass">(.*?)</span>)*|', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
exit;
```

The `<span class="anotherClass">entry</span>` can not exists or exists multiple times, the pattern seems to match it fine works both when exists and when it doesn't, but the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <div class="className">AlwaysTheSame:</div>Subtitle <br /><span class="anotherClass">entry1</span><span class="anotherClass">entry2</span><span class="anotherClass">entry3</span>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Subtitle 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => <span class="anotherClass">entry3</span>
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => entry3
        )

)
```

Array[0][0] contains the full string so its matching all I need, but in Array[2] and [3] I only get the last `<span...`

How can I get all those `<span...` in the output array and not just the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly, at least not in PHP. Repeated capturing groups always contain the last expression they matched. [The exception is .NET where regex matches have an additional property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx) that allows you to access every single match of a repeated group. Also, Perl 6 can do something like this - but not PHP.

Solution: Use

```
~<div class="className">AlwaysTheSame:</div>(.*?)<br />((?:<span class="anotherClass">(.*?)</span>)*)~
```

Now the second capturing group contains *all*  the `<span>` tags. With another regex you can then extract all the matches:

```
~(?<=<span class="anotherClass">).*?(?=</span>)~
```

I'm using `~` as a regex delimiter, by the way - using `|` is confusing IMO.